# What do you call the work done to make an encyclopedia or a reference book?

Tags: word-request

There are many reference book, but I mostly mean by that a book that list concepts and organize them like most encyclopedia, but not necessarily an encyclopedia. What do you call the work done to make such reference books? I was thinking research, but research doesn't cover the part of organizing your ideas by theme, or whatever other way of organizing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're right that half this work could be described as "research." The act of bringing it all together could be termed "compilation."

> n., the action or process of producing something, especially a list, book, or report, by assembling information collected from other sources.

The verb is "to compile."

Answer (score 2):

I expect the official title for the person who does this job is the same as for any other book: *editor*.  But this particular action can be variously described as *compile, collate*, and *catalogue*, depending on the specifics.